# Python Random variables graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib

I use this code to print out 4 graphs of 4 possibilities for discrete random variable but I can't find a way to put them in the right shape and size. If you test the code you will see the 4 graphs very close to each other and the titles are covering each other. Here is my code:

```
from scipy.stats import poisson
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=range(1,21)
rv=poisson(5)
figure(1)

subplot(2,2,1)
plt.bar(x,rv.pmf(x))
plt.title('Poisson R.V for x=[1,21] and lambda=5')
plt.xlabel('Random Variable')
plt.ylabel('Probability')


x= range(1,21)
rv= poisson(10)
subplot(2,2,2)
plt.bar(x,rv.pmf(x))
plt.title('Poisson R.V for x=[1,21] and lambda=10')
plt.xlabel('Random Variable')
plt.ylabel('Probability')


x= range(1,21)
rv= poisson(15)
subplot(2,2,3)
plt.bar(x,rv.pmf(x))
plt.title('Poisson R.V for x=[1,21] and lambda=15')
plt.xlabel('Random Variable')
plt.ylabel('Probability')

x= range(1,21)
rv= poisson(20)
subplot(2,2,4)
plt.bar(x,rv.pmf(x))
plt.title('Poisson R.V for x=[1,21] and lambda=20')
plt.xlabel('Random Variable')
plt.ylabel('Probability')


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the size of the figure, then change the size of the letters with:

```
plt.title('text', size=10)
plt.xlabel('text', size=10)
plt.ylabel('text', size=10)
```

and add some space between the plots with:

```
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.4, hspace=0.4).
```

A faster way to change the font size is:

```
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 8})
```

Comment: what i wanted is to change the size of the drawings cuase they are too small and i want them in one pic together but i already sloved this using :

Comment: plt.subplots_adjust(left=1,bottom=None,right=3,top=2,wspace=0.3,hspace=0.5)
at the end of the code

Comment: @Al-MeqdadJabi You should add it as an answer to your own question. And it doesn't hurt to be a little more specific when you're asking a question.